# Secure SOAP Server in Google App Engine Standard (Python or PHP)

Tags: google-app-engine, soap, google-app-engine-python, google-app-engine-php

I have a project to connect with Banks in Chile and they communicate only with **secured SOAP** services (exchanging SSL keys).  I need to implement both client (from my app to banks servers) and server (the bank will make SOAP request to my GAE app) requests.

What are the libraries required in Python/PHP in case this is possible?  Any experience to share?

All my app is designed in GAE standard so I'm avoiding to use GCE o GAE flexible, and I have no experience in Java, so I kindly appreciate answers only for **GAE standard Python/PHP**.

Comment: The documentation in GAE was deleted (404 error) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/soap?hl=vi

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to first have a look on the [conceptual PHP documentation for GAE standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime) and the [GAE standard quickstart for PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/quickstart).

Once you understand the basic concepts, you could try this [SOAP server guide in PHP](https://dev.to/dopitz/implementing-a-soap-api-with-php-a3n). I don't have experience on SOAP servers but the guide looks good, at first sight.

Good luck!